# DynamoDB: Expected value operators for deleteItem (or putItem) calls?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to add a condition to a `deleteItem` call that will be evaluated prior to deleting the item. (For the sake of this example, the DynamoDB table name is `TABLE_NAME`).

```
TABLE_NAME.imported_timestamp value is less than timestamp of 60 days ago
```

I could have sworn there is a way to do this, but I haven't been able to find any definitive documentation or discussion on the matter. The following PHP code block is what I have right now..

```
$cmp_timestamp = strtotime('-60 days');
$dynamo->deleteItem(array(
    'TableName' => 'TABLE_NAME',
    'Key' => array(
        'HashKeyElement' => array('S' => 'my_hash_key_element')
    ),
    'Expected' => array(
        'imported_timestamp' => array('Value' => array('N' => $cmp_timestamp))
    )
));
```

Currently, the above code will check if `TABLE_NAME.imported_timestamp` value is equal to the value of `$cmp_timestamp`. Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to do either a `Query` or `Scan` on your table depending on your key schema to get the keys of the items you want to delete. Then you can use `BatchWriteItem` to delete the items.

The DynamoDB Session Handler that ships with the PHP SDK does exactly this type of thing in its garbage collection method, so you may be interested in [checking out that implementation](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/master/src/Aws/DynamoDb/Session/SessionHandler.php#L378-L447). The SDK uses a `Scan` Iterator along with the `WriteRequestBatch` class to do this. The `WriteRequestBatch` class is nice because it makes doing the batch delete calls easier and handles some of the edge cases for you. There are [some docs for it in the AWS SDK for PHP User Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/service-dynamodb.html#using-the-writerequestbatch).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to do this with Dynamo DB. As a workaround you can query/scan the table to find the items, and then loop and delete them with `DeleteItem`.

Comment: I will wait a few more hours to see if anyone else has an idea, but this may actually be the only decent way to accomplish what I need.

Comment: Actually, batch deletes are supported via BatchWriteItem. It can do puts and deletes.